# Treatment of Existing Models in a Stage When Transitioning Models

Tags: python, mlflow

With the MLflow client library, it is possible to transition models through stages as shown below,

```
client = MlflowClient()
client.transition_model_version_stage(
    name="sk-learn-random-forest-reg-model",
    version=3,
    stage="Production"
)
```

Upon doing some testing, I noticed that this does not in any way affect the model(s) that are currently in the stage that the model was transitioned to.

For example, let's say version 2 of a given model is in Production. This will remain tagged as a Production model, even if I were to move version 3 to Production as well.

Is there any way that I can control what happens to models that exist in a stage when making transitions using the above code?

Basically, I only want one version of a model to be in a given stage at a time.

This functionality is available when transitioning models through the Databricks UI,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed the `archive_existing_versions=True` that comes with the `transition_model_version_stage` function.

This flag defaults to `False`.

The documentation is available here,

https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tracking.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.transition_model_version_stage